# scrolling down in browser C#

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0

I have this `browsercontroller` and wonder how can I scroll down to the bottom of the page? I don't know the right command for this one

Here is my part of my code

```
Browser browserController = new Browser(); //call browser controlle
Searcher searchKey = new Searcher();
browserController.browserCloser("iexplore"); //close all recent open IE to avoid issues
using (IE browser = new IE(browserController.URLData())) //original code but with time out exception
{
    browser.AutoClose = false;
    browser.WaitForComplete(40);

    Thread.Sleep(20000);
}
```

I need to scroll down to the IE  and wait for the item to load 
this is the website I'm checking https://hpe.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/Jobsathpe/
I need to load all the results in the page

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Thread.Sleep()` in UI thread. It usualy blocks any UI actions even these which was invoked just before this call. Use `Timer` instead.

Comment: shouldn't be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Codebehind:

- [scrollTo method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159577(v=vs.110).aspx)
- create a control at the bottom of the page... and [Focus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178232.aspx)

Client side:

- [scrollTo, scrollBy](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_win_scrollto.asp)

Comment: I'm new to C# and I don't have that scrollTo or Scrollby method in the browser

Comment: Follow the links and puzzle about it ;) If it's too much, maybe you should start reading some beginner's documentation